ERROR: "start:disconnected-proxy" exited with 1 next js
Writing component builder to C:\New Commercial FrontEnd\New Commercial FrontEnd\Frontend-Commercial\src\temp\componentBuilder.ts
Writing runtime config to C:\New Commercial FrontEnd\New Commercial FrontEnd\Frontend-Commercial\src\temp\config.js
Nothing to do. Caches for 2 GraphQL documents are fresh.

msilcommercial@21.2.0 next:dev
cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev


msilcommercial@21.2.0 start:disconnected-proxy
ts-node --project tsconfig.scripts.json ./scripts/disconnected-mode-proxy.ts


msilcommercial@21.2.0 start:watch-components
ts-node --project tsconfig.scripts.json scripts/generate-component-builder/index.ts --watch

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/308488e2-a147-44c8-ae23-93342b73a132
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59710/11a7c2e8-4ebb-4dbc-9743-eba4cdac7b4e
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
info Loaded env from C:\New Commercial FrontEnd\New Commercial FrontEnd\Frontend-Commercial.env
warn You have enabled experimental feature (isrMemoryCacheSize) in next.config.js.
warn Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.

Watching for changes to component builder sources in src/components...

info the --inspect option was detected, the Next.js server for pages should be inspected at port 59715.
path or pattern './sitecore/pipelines/**/*.patch.js' did not match any files.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59715/95c6dcb0-4720-4106-a7fd-7505a183ae78
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
info Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
The manifest defined duplicate template names: HeaderBannerAnimation. This is not allowed.
info automatically enabled Fast Refresh for 1 custom loader
event compiled client and server successfully in 515 ms (18 modules)
ERROR: "start:disconnected-proxy" exited with 1.
node:events:496
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error:

spawn npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel next:dev
start:disconnected-proxy start:watch-components ENOENT
at notFoundError (C:\New Commercial FrontEnd\New Commercial FrontEnd\Frontend-Commercial\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
at verifyENOENT (C:\New Commercial FrontEnd\New Commercial FrontEnd\Frontend-Commercial\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)

at cp.emit (C:\New Commercial FrontEnd\New Commercial FrontEnd\Frontend-Commercial\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12) Emitted 'error' event on

ChildProcess instance at:
at cp.emit (C:\New Commercial FrontEnd\New Commercial FrontEnd\Frontend-Commercial\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12) {   code: 'ENOENT',   errno:
'ENOENT',   syscall: 'spawn npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel
next:dev start:disconnected-proxy start:watch-components',   path:
'npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel next:dev
start:disconnected-proxy start:watch-components',   spawnargs: [] }

Node.js v20.11.1
PS C:\New Commercial FrontEnd\New Commercial FrontEnd\Frontend-Commercial>
when i am trying to start project getting this error npm run start
